# How do I select N users at time from a specific table (with loop maybe)?

Tags: sql, linux, mariadb

I want to query a database and insert all users in a tables in files but I want to do that in three time. For example, if in the table Users I have 300 users, I select 100 users once, then 100 and at the end 100.

How can I do it?

`select id from users where ... >> Files.csv`

It is a script bash. I have already my select request but I do it only once, this is not good as I have many records in that tables.

Comment: Use [LIMIT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/limit/)

Comment: if i do select id from users limit 100 it is not what i want exactly. 

I have millions users to insert in the csv files, And I want to select all millions users but sequentially. 
for exemple : While $count > 10000000 do: select id from users limit 100 >> files.csv till all users are inserted in mycsv file as i say sequentially with just one request. 

I don't know how to do that with a loop.

Comment: LIMIT has OFFSET option.